# RewriteRule и знак вопроса

Tags: apache, регулярные-выражения, mod_rewrite, .htaccess

Приветствую.

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой: имеется ссылка вида

> http://site.net/action/value1?var2=value2&var3=value3&...

необходимо сделать перенаправление на

> http://site.net/action=value1&var2=value2&var3=value3&...

через http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ удалось написать правило

```
RewriteRule ^action/([^/]*)\?(.+)/?$ ?action=$1&$2 [QSA,R,L]
```

в конструкторе это правило всё форматирует прекрасно, а вот на сайте почему-то не работает. Знак вопроса обнаруживается, только если его не экранировать, но тогда ссылка искажается

> http://site.net/?action=value&1&var2=value2...

Comment: Я б сформулировал так: если возникают подобные трудности, то что-то нужно править в консерватории :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вопрос решился следующим образом

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+)$
RewriteRule ^action/([^/]*)/?$ ?action=$1&%1 [R,L]
```

Comment: Не совсем верно.  

    ^action/([^/]*)/\?$
Ваша ошибка в вопросе в том, что `[^/]*` ищет до слэша, но не включает его, соответственно после `[^/]` надо искать слэш, а не знак вопроса.  
Выражение в ответе означает, что после `[^/]*` может быть, а может и не быть слэш, но он там всегда есть.

Comment: Господа, не работает ни так, ни с поправкой в комментах. Как быть?